# Firebase Firestore Where Operator Using Nested Dynamic Properties

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Using the below model I need to use the `where` operator when querying Firestore. However, the `where` property is nested based on a variable code below:

```
where("category", "==", "Something"),
```

### Model

```
const language = "EN"

{ 
    EN: {
        category: "Something in english"
    },
    FR: {
        category: "Something in french"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So what's the question for us?

Comment: @AlexMamo What do I change where(“something”) to? - something like… where(“language”.category)

Comment: Can y ou please show us a screenshot of your document?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added a screenshot - there will be the same structure for FR and other languages etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to query a collection based on the value that exists inside a map, then you should use a `where` function call that looks like this:

```
where("EN.category", "==", "Some Category")
```

If you need to change the language, then you should consider using a variable rather than a hard-coded value. In code, it should look like this:

```
where('${language}.category', "==", "Some Category")
```

Comment: kindly note that "EN" will be a variable - how will I include this?

Comment: Most likely like this `'${language}.category'`,  right?

Comment: yes. This is working - please update answer so I can mark as correct.